# Passing C struct to Cython and converting to Python numpy array

Tags: python, cython

## main.h

```
ifndef MAIN_H
define MAIN_H

ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
endif

typedef struct Pythonout{
    int pn;
    double *px;
}Pythonout;

struct Pythonout l1tf_main(char *ifile_y, double lambda, int rflag);


ifdef __cplusplus
}
endif

endif /* MAIN_H */
```

> Following is the Cython `pyx` file using `main.h`

## .pyx

```
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "main.h":
    ctypedef struct Pythonout:
        int n
        double *x
    cdef Pythonout l1tf_main(char *ifile_y 
                            ,double lambdaval, 
                             int rflag);

cdef class Pyclass:
    cdef Pythonout pnx

    def __cinit__(self, char *pfilename, 
                  lambdaval, rflag):
        self.pnx = l1tf_main(pfilename, 
                             lambdaval, rflag)

    @property
    def n(self):
        return self.pnx.n

    @property
    def x(self):
        cdef np.npy_float64 shape[1]
        shape[0] = <np.npy_intp> self.pnx.n
        ndarray = 
                 np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, 
                 &(self.pnx.n),np.NPY_FLOAT64, 
                 <void *> self.pnx.x)
        np.PyArray_UpdateFlags(ndarray, 
                               ndarray.flags.num 
                               | np.NPY_OWNDATA)
        return ndarray

cpdef filtered_trend(char *pfilename, double 
                     lambdaval, int rflag):
    pnx = Pyclass(pfilename, lambdaval, rflag)
    return pnx.x
```

In the class I am getting the following error while compiling:

> ‘Pythonout {aka struct Pythonout}’ has no member named ‘n’
>
> ‘Pythonout {aka struct Pythonout}’ has no member named ‘x’

When calling the object value `pnx.n` and `pnx.x`.

Comment: If I add the line `cimport numpy as np` to the start, and add a slash the `ndarray = ` (for the line continuation) this code compiles fine in Cython. I suspect your error is at the C compiling stage. Since you don't show `main.h` this is impossible for anyone but you to diagnose. Please read the help on [mcve] and make sure that you have provided one.

Comment: Thank you, David, for your reply. Here is how my `main.h` looks like:

Answer (score 0):

There's at least two issues with your code.

1. The trivial issue causing the compilation errors: in C you call the struct attributes `px` and `pn`, while in Cython you call them `x` and `n`. This means that the code Cython generates does not match the C header. Make these consistent.
2. ```
   np.PyArray_UpdateFlags(ndarray, 
                          ndarray.flags.num 
                          | np.NPY_OWNDATA)
   ```

   This tells Numpy that in now owns the data in `x` and is responsible for deallocating it. However suppose you have the Python code:

   ```
   x1 = PyClassInstance.x
   x2 = PyClassInstance.x
   ```

   You now have two Numpy arrays that each believe the own the same data and will both try to deallocate it. (Similarly if you never access `x` then `pnx.x` is never deallocated) What you should probably do is have the `PyClass` instance be responsible for deallocating its `pnx.x` (in a `__dealloc__` function). Then in your `x` property do:

   ```
   ndarray = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(...)
   Py_INCREF(self) # SetBaseObject doesn't do this so you must do it manually
   PyArray_SetBaseObject(ndarray, self) # check return value for errors...
   ```

   Now the Numpy array treats the `PyClass` instance as owning the data.